# Removing an object from array with splice() does not work as expected in React

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I am creating input fields dynamically based on the number of object in my state array. Beside each field I am adding a button to remove that field. However, when the button is clicked it behaves in an unexpected way.

Below is the visual demonstration:

When I press "Remove Option" button on "*Option 0*":

[image: here]

The output is like :

[image: this]

However, when I see from `console.log()` the correct object is being removed. These are `console.log()` outputs before:

[image: before]

and after the above button click:

[image: after]

Here is how I loop from the array in my `render()`:

```
const questions = this.state.values_array.map((question, index) => {


 return ( 
    <div key = {question.question_id}>   
    {this.state.options_array.map((option, i) => (
        option.questionID === question.question_id ? //to show only this question's options
          <div>
              <span>Option {i}:</span>
              <TextField type="text" defaultValue={option.description} />
              <span>Value:</span>
              <TextField type="number" defaultValue={option.value}/>
              <button onClick={() => this.removeOption(i)}>Remove Option</button>
          </div>
        :
          null
    ))}
    </div>
    )
  }
```

Here is my `removeOption()` method I am using to remove the input fields:

```
removeOption(index){

    let options = [...this.state.options_array];
    options.splice(index, 1);
    this.setState({ options_array: options });
}
```

And here is how I am calling it in my render's return:

```
 return (
   <div>{questions}</div>
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the keys for the `div` containers. React needs to know which DOM Element has been removed so it re-renders it. Also, do not use the `index` of `map` as the key, instead use something like the id e.g. `option.questionID`.

Answer (score 1):

The flaw of this approach is that in JavaScript, **objects and arrays are reference types**, so when we get an array, we actually get a pointer to the original array's object managed by react. If we then splice it, we already mutate the original data and whilst it does work without throwing an error, this is not really how we should do it, this can lead to unpredictable apps and is definitely a bad practice. A good practice is to create a copy of the  array before manipulating it and a simple way of doing this is by calling the slice method. Slice without arguments simply copies the full array and returns a new one which is then stored. And we can now safely edit this new one and then update to react state with our new array. let me give you and example:

We have an array like this `const arr=[1,2,3,4,5]`. This is original array.

As I told you before, we can do that like this:

```
const newVar=arr.slice();
newVar.splice(Index,1);
console.log(newVar);
```

**Or**

An alternative to this approach would be to use it a ES6 feature, it is the **Spread Operator**

Our prior code can be something like this:

```
const newVar=[...arr]
newVar.splice(Index,1);
console.log(newVar);
```

That's it. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

you need to filter out the individual item from the list

```
removeOption(index) {
const options = this.state.options_array.filter((items, itemIndex) => itemIndex 
!== index)
this.setState({ options_array: options });}
```